# Cut JS string present in an array at every occurrance of a particular substring and append to same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, indexof

**Note:** 
At this point in time, I'm unable to word the question title better. If someone is able to put it accross better, please go right ahead!

**What I have:**

```
var array = ["authentication.$.order", "difference.$.user.$.otherinformation", ... , ...]
```

**What I need:**

```
["authentication", "authentication.$", "authentication.$.order",
"difference", "difference.$", "difference.$.user", "difference.$.user.$", 
"difference.$.user.$.otherinformation"]
```

Basically, wherevever I see `.$.`, I need to preserve it, then append everything before the occourrence of `.$.` along with everything before the occourrence of `.$`

**Example:**

`difference.$.user.$.otherinformation` should be parsed to contain:

```
difference
difference.$
difference.$.user
difference.$.user.$
difference.$.user.$.otherinformation
```

I'm strongly feeling that some sort of recursion is to be involved here, but have not progressed in that direction yet.

Below is my implementation for the same, but unfortunately, my when my substring matches the first occourrence of `.$.`, it stops and does not proceed to further check for other occurrences of `.$.` in the same string.

How best can I take this to closure?

**Current flawed implementation:**

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    //  next, replace all array field references with $ as that is what autoform's pick() requires
    //  /\.\d+\./g,".$." ==> replace globally .[number]. with .$.    
    array[i] = array[i].replace(/\.\d+\./g,".$.");
        if(array[i].substring(0, array[i].lastIndexOf('.$.'))){
            console.log("Substring without .$.  " + array[i].substring(0, array[i].indexOf('.$.')));
            console.log("Substring with .$ " + array[i].substring(0, array[i].indexOf('.$.')).concat(".$"));
            array.push(array[i].substring(0, array[i].indexOf('.$.')).concat(".$"));
            array.push(array[i].substring(0, array[i].indexOf('.$.')));
            }
        }
    // finally remove any duplicates if any
    array = _.uniq(array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional single liner could be;

```js
var array  = ["authentication.$.order", "difference.$.user.$.otherinformation"],
    result = array.reduce((r,s) => r.concat(s.split(".").reduce((p,c,i) => p.concat(i ? p[p.length-1] + "." + c : c), [])), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: By far the shortest answer in terms of compactness but complex in terms of understandibility. Would you please be able to explain how this actually works?

Comment: What if the array contains values like: `"www.example.com."`?

Comment: @hindmost - Good question, but my initial array will never contain something that is ending with a ```.``` so I suppose it's safe to assume.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function inside your array loop.

```js
var test = "difference.$.user.$.otherinformation";

function toArray(testString) {
  var testArr = testString.split(".")

  var tempString = "";
  var finalArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {

    var toTest = testArr[i];

    if (toTest == "$") {
      tempString += ".$"
    } else {
      if (i != 0) {
        tempString += ".";
      }

      tempString += toTest;
    }

    finalArray.push(tempString)

  } 
  return finalArray;
}
console.log(toArray(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a Regex expression to grab everything until the last occurrence of `.$` and the chopped it, until there was nothing left. Reverse at the end.

```
let results = [];
let found = true;

const regex = /^(.*)\.\$/g;
let str = `difference.\$.user.\$.otherinformation`;
let m;

results.push(str);
while(found) {
    found = false;
    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        if(m.length > 0) {
            found = true;
            results.push(m[0]);
            str = m[1];
        }
    }
}
results.push(str);
results = results.reverse();
// Concat this onto another array and keep concatenating for the other strings
console.log(results);
```

You will just need to loop this over your array, store the results in a temp array and keep concatenating them onto a final array.

https://jsfiddle.net/9pa3hr46/

Comment: This is a bit off... Result is: ```difference,difference.$,difference.$.user.$,difference.$.user.$.otherinformation``` Notice that ```difference.$.user``` has been skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```
 const dat = ["authentication.$.order", "difference.$.user.$.otherinformation"];

 const ret = dat.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const props = val.split('.');
    let concat = '';
    return acc.concat(props.reduce((acc1, prop) => {
      concat+= (concat ? '.'+ prop : prop);
      acc1.push(concat);
      return acc1;
    }, []));
 }, [])

 console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `for` loop like below:

```js
var str = "difference.$.user.$.otherinformation";
var sub, initial = "";
var start = 0;
var pos = str.indexOf('.');
for (; pos != -1; pos = str.indexOf('.', pos + 1)) {
  sub = str.substring(start, pos);
  console.log(initial + sub);
  initial += sub;
  start = pos;
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually recursion is unnecessary for this problem. You can use regular loop with subloop instead.

All you need is:

1. split each occurence in the array into substrings;
2. build a series of accumulated values from these substrings;
3. replace the current element of the array with this series.

Moreover, in order to make replacement to work properly you have to iterate the array in reverse order. BTW in this case you don't need to remove duplicates in the array.

So the code should look like this:

```js
var array = ["authentication.$.order", "difference.$.user.$.otherinformation"];

var SEP = '.$.';
for (var i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    var v = array[i];
    var subs = v.replace(/\.\d+\./g, SEP).split(SEP)
    if (subs.length <= 1) continue;
    var acc = subs[0], elems = [acc];
    for (var n = subs.length-1, j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        elems[j * 2 + 1] = (acc += SEP);
        elems[j * 2 + 2] = (acc += subs[j]);
    }
    array.splice.apply(array, [i, 1].concat(elems));
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I gave this code snippet a go in chrome console in order to understand what's going on. However, the output seems to be a bit off of what was required. Output: ```,difference.$.,difference.$.difference,difference.$.difference.$.,difference.$.difference.$.user```

Comment: @blueren Sorry, I forgot to initialize `elems` with `subs[0]`. Now it works